# Cisco 6500 Sup Engine 720 rate limiting per port basis

Tags: networking, cisco

I was just wondering if its possible to rate limit both ingress and egress traffic on a cisco 6500 with a supervisor 720 engine. I've looked on cisco's website and the only way to do it i've found is through routed vlan's.

Is there a way to do this to manage traffic on a per port basis? IE We have a different customer off of each port and we would like to rate limit the port to 5 - 10 -15 - 20 megs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention exactly which 720 you've got but you need 12.2(25) and the following command, look at its help and follow your nose;

> srr-queue bandwidth

Oh and [THIS](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps708/white_paper_c11_538840.html) link may help too.